# Trying to build GNU Icecat Browser from tarball in Debian

Tags: debian, compiling, tar, make, firefox

I got the `icecat-52.3.0-gnu1.tar.bz2` file from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnuzilla/52.3.0/, then followed the directions in the readme as follows:

```
tar xvjf ~/Downloads/icecat-52.3.0-gnu1.tar.bz2

mkdir /opt/icecat

cd /opt/icecat
```

Everything worked fine, until this step:

`~/icecat-52.3.0/configure --with-l10n-base=~/icecat-52.3.0/l10n`

Which spits out:

`ERROR: Invalid value --with-l10n-base, ~/icecat-52.3.0/l10n doesn't exist`

So I checked the ~/icecat-52.3.0/l10n file, and it does exist, so I have no idea what could be causing this. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok so I did `/home/jimmy/icecat-52.3.0/configure --with-l10n-base=/home/jimmy/icecat-52.3.0/l10n`, now I get `ERROR: The pkg-config script could not be found. Make sure it is in your path, or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full path to pkg-config.`

Comment: Install the _pkg-config_ package and try again.